# How to include a model inside my index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two model `Event`, and `Photo` with the following relationships:

Event

```
has_many :photos
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos, :allow_destroy => true
```

Photo

```
belongs_to :event
```

When I create it in my `Event#new` controller I have the following

```
@event = Event.new
@event.photos.build
```

This is my `Event#form` view inside the form

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
...
  <%= fields_for :photos do |photo| %>
    <%= photo.file_field :picture %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And now I want to include the first photo because you may have more than one set related to this to show in `Event#index`.

I try this but it seem to fails:

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
  <% event.photos.first do |pict| %>
    <%= pict.image... %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: done that too it show me nothing, I just look at rails and the reason is because it never create the picture into the database

Comment: The issue is you need to implement f.fields_for some site suggest not, but in this case it must be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<%= fields_for :photos do |photo| %>` into `<%= f.fields_for :photos do |photo| %>`.

`<% event.photos.first do |pict| %>` is wrong - just get first picture and try accessing it (if it exists):

```
<% pict = event.photos.first %>
<% if pict %>
code here
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add :multipart => true to your form_for block if you have a file field in the form. That could explain why it's not uploading.

Comment: "Since Rails 3.1, forms rendered using form_for have their encoding set to multipart/form-data automatically once a file_field is used inside the block. Previous versions required you to set this explicitly." http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files

Comment: So i dont need? Cause i just try and unfortunotly it didn't get save to the database the log look fines it see the parameters

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that it doesn't do anything because #first doesn't take a block. Try

```
<%= event.photos.first.image... %>
```

event.photos.first returns a single object, and passing a block (e.g. the do |photo| ... end part) to an object doesn't really do anything.

BTW, it would be helpful if you include a little more detail on what "it fails" means. Do you get a stack trace? Does nothing show on the page? Have you verified in the console that your Event object has one or more Photos?